# Should all data member be hidden?

Tags: c++, oop

I know the 'data hiding' concept of OOP, but in real devolopment it always is challanged  when the specications are changed.

For example:

```
class role
{
    std::string name;
    int level;
    public:
        const std::string& get_name() { return name; }
        void set_name(const std::string& value) { name = value; }
        void set_level(int value) { level = value; }
        int get_level() const { return level; }
}
```

Of course, there is nothing wrong with this code. But `name` and `level` are't encapsulated at all, I thought.

My opinions as follows:

1. User can modify data by setter function.
2. setter/getter **expose data type of those data member**. If those data member have to change their type, setter/getter function member have to **change their interfaces,too.**
3. If I need another operation for `level` member, adding more operation member (e.q `add_level(int value)` or `sub_level(int value)` etc.) functions is the only way.
4. Just one thing is fine. If `get/set` have to add some judgements to them, these interfaces can work well.

So, **what kind of data member should I encapsulate**? I can't predict the scale and usage at all with those data members. If I expose them directly, operations on them will be completly simple, clear, and make sense. If I encapsulate them, I would make lots of operation members for them, and if someday their type changed by spec (int -> class, class -> int), my operation members must change their interface or kill them all directly (because I will send them to public zone, once for all!).

Comment: http://www.idinews.com/quasiClass.pdf

Comment: Getters and setters are useless when it comes to encapsulation. Just make the members public if you want people to be able to modify them. No excuses. Even better, don’t use OOP at all and you won’t have all these problems.

Comment: You have a direct mapping between data and public interface with all your getters and setters. This isn't very OO at all.

Comment: If you feel the need to expose data members directly, then it's likely that the responsibility of the class has not been thought out very well.

Comment: @daknøk: that's not quite true, if you were to return from the getter by copy (instead of a reference), then the internal type would be completely encapsulated and changed without any impact for the clients. Obviously, some types are cheaper to copy than others...

Comment: Thanks you all for responding.
I know the setter and getter breaks the encasulation entirely, no metion if I make another operation members. So, it seems I can expose those fields may not changed type?
Ooops, more over. "Don't use OOP" isn't an option, thanks.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been reading on many different languages, and notably functional languages, and I have slowly come to question the idea of *setters*.

Suppose that I have a class `Person`, this is what I would have written some years ago:

```
class Person {
public:
    std::string const& name() const { return _name; }
    void name(std::string const& n) { _name = n; }

    unsigned age() const { return _age; }
    void age(unsigned a) { _age = a; }

private:
    std::string _name;
    unsigned _age;
};
```

You will note how similar it is to your own class.

- Will the name of a `Person` change during the lifetime of the object ?
- Will the age of a `Person` change during the lifetime of the object ? What could be we do to avoid this situation ?
- I have tied myself down regarding the type of `_name`: changing it would break the `name()` getter...

And now, an alternative implementation, which is what I would write today:

```
class Person {
public:
    Person(std::string name, Time birth): _name(name), _birth(birth) {}

    std::string name() const { return _name; }

    Duration age(Time now) { return now - _birth; }

private:
    std::string _name;
    Time _birth;
};
```

This class *no longer have any setter*. This class *no longer return any handle to its internals* (I'll pay the price of the copy therefore, probably won't amount to much anyway).

The most notable point however is that I changed how I memorized the information: the `age` is a fluctuating value derived from the birth date and the current date. Therefore, why memorizing a byproduct rather the source ?

And I want to change the value ? Well:

```
Time const now = Time::Now();
person = Person("John R. Smith", now - person.age(now));
```

works well enough. And at least I only write my invariants once (in the constructor).

Obviously, this does not necessarily applies everywhere. If your class only has a few fields though it works well; when your class gets more fields, maybe it's time to extract some of them into classes of their own.

Comment: My opinion #3 mensions **the other operation members**.
Setter and getter is the simplest problem in my concern. Major problem is **uncountable** operation members I should implemented if any spec changed.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that the class defines an *interface*, which is a contract between its authors and any developers who use it.  The interface should remain as constant as possible, because any changes to the interface may necessitate changes to the code that uses it.

Writing setters and getters means you can validate accesses to the private members, and you can change the underlying implementation (for example, by changing the internal data types) without affecting any of the client code.

For example, suppose you've written a `time` class.  Your setters can prevent callers from storing invalid values in the `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` members.  And suppose the values are retrieved from a real-time clock.  Your getters can query the RTC and return error codes if it's inaccessible or broken.

As another example, suppose you've defined a getter that returns a 32-bit integer.  You later discover an inaccuracy that can be fixed by changing the implementation to use 64-bit integers.  (Perhaps it's doing some sort of calculation that gets rounded to 32 bits.)  The getter encapsulates the implementation, so you're free to update it to use 64 bits internally but still return a (now more accurate) 32-bit value, so your new class is a drop-in replacement for the old one.

Comment: One point: this is fine as long as you return by value, but breaks whenever you return by reference (even `const`).

Comment: I don't see how *not* using a getter/setter would prevent refactoring the implenetation for 64bits. Only if you have a pressing current need for get/set should you use them. Otherwise just use public access and refactor when the time comes.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I don't understand.  _Not_ using a getter/setter _wouldn't_ prevent refactoring.  That's the point.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. There's no value in adding get/set methods before you need them since you can simply alter the code and add them later.

Comment: Adding setters/getters later (that is, changing the interface of your class) means everyone who uses your code must change their code to match.  That's often impractical, and it will certainly make you unpopular if your code is widely used.

Answer (score 1):

Getters and setters are usually only useful when you do something more than just assigning a member variable.

```
class A {
public:
  int get_value () const;
  void set_value (int v);

private:
  int _value;
};
```

The above doesn't really buy you anything if you 1) never intend to change the implementation (basically you are not coding against an interface), 2) there is no validation to be performed.

When your class consists of data which do not share an invariant (basically the class just collects different values but there are no rules between the members) you can argue whether getters and setters are useful.

For example in the case of a Date class you should really use setters and getters because the members (day, month and year) share an invariant (e.g. when month is incremented above 12, year should be incremented aswell).

However in the case of a Point class where X and Y do not share an invariant you can skip the getters and setters unless you really want to make it an interface and use polymorphism.

Also I do not agree that OOP is challenging because the specifications change (they always do anyway) but correctly used OOP is a technique (combined with others) which can help you cope with change and isolate parts of your program from each other so that change does not trickle through your entire codebase. I wouldn't say that there are any simple rules you can follow so that this just works instead this is a question of experience.

Answer (score 0):

1. use set/get to modify values from OUTSIDE the class(say from another class).
2. hide functions(with private) that NEED NOT be exposed outside the class. For example I have a class which has functions to compute Integration using various methods. But all of those algorithms rely on a function called sumIt() which should NOT be used by other classes explicitly.
3. If you want to avoid writing your own getters/setters manually each time, you can easily, using templates, extend C++ to allow "property" like modifiers.
   It depends on the design of your class/application.

Comment: they're easier than getSomething() and setSomething(); just use obj.Something = foo;

Comment: a little syntactic sugar to make things seem easier to read/grasp